# Ubuntu вместо Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, ос

Перевели меня на новый проект. Архитектор сказал, что нужно однозначно менять ОС на UNIX-подобную, так как у меня по другому просто не выйдет на нем (проекте) работать.

Как типичный пользователь Windows, я постарался найти, как поставить Ubuntu. Столкнулся с тем, что даже у нужной версии есть какие-то там TLC или как это правильно называется, а также различные вариации. Также я не понял, как ее вообще правильно поставить на ноутбук, чтобы полноценно пользоваться.

Может кто-нибудь дать ссылку на ресурс, где можно определить нужную редакцию Ubuntu 14.04, и коротко описать, какая нужна конфигурация для старта на этой ОС. Сроки очень сжатые, а потому разбираться в книгах по *nix системам времени нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38525/discussion-on-question-by-trembling11-ubuntu--windows).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Кратко:

1. Не сносите Windows - это не обязательно. Сделайте дуалбут, для подстраховки. Освободите место под раздел HDD ~30 GB. При установке Ubuntu найдет раздел с Windows и добавит вам пункт меню в GRUB (начальный загрузчик).
2. Выберите [DE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0). Ubuntu поставляется в нескольких дистрибутивах с разными DE. Чтобы первый раз не путаться в глобальных меню возьмите классику: Xubuntu или Ubuntu Mate. Превью можете посмотреть на YouTube.
3. [Ставьте 16.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/). Формально это бета, но релиз через неделю.
4. В Linux софт принято ставить из репозиториев. Официальных или сторонних. Сторонние репозитории в Ubuntu называются PPA. Java устаналивается из PPA [webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java):

Установка Java:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends oracle-java6-installer oracle-java7-installer oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends oracle-java8-set-default
```

После установки ищите их в `/usr/lib/jvm`

5. В Linux перед вами может снова встать вопрос выбора IDE. Нормально выглядит только Eclipse при отключенной поддержке GTK3. Для остальных требуются манипуляции в виде установки openjdk-fontfix. Если вы пишете в NetBeans, сочувствую, его не спасает ничто.
6. Осваивайте гугл: ubuntu + 3 слова на инглише, описывающие суть вопроса, творят чудеса.
7. Можно ещё заглянуть [сюда](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0_ubuntu-linux_-_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82p%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_windows)

Comment: Нормальный Netbeans был. Ни чуть не хуже остальных программ для линуха. А вот кто начинает спасать, устанавливая всякие чёрные темы, тому и в виндовсе не поздоровится

Answer (score 5):

В Ubuntu, четные версии являются стабильными, а нечетные - для разработки. Поэтому, если вы хотите уменьшить вероятность столкнуться с багами, лучше использовать стабильные версии с поддержкой в 5 лет (их называют LTS дистрибутивами): сейчас стабильной версией является 14.04 (2014 - год, 04 - месяц выпуска), для неё выпускаются обновления (близкая windows-аналогия: сервис паки), которые нумеруются 14.04.X, последний 14.04.4 - лучше взять его.

В апреле 2016 должен выйти новый стабильный релиз 16.04 (2016 год, 04 - апрель) - возможно он вам подойдет лучше, так как на ноутбуках бывают проблемы с драйверами особенно для видеокарт, если вы сталкиваетесь со сложностями в установке разрешения, возможно в этой версии проблема для вашего ноутбука будет решена. Кроме того рекомендуется установить проприетарные драйвера по меньше мере для видеокарты, если, конечно, они имеются (во время установки или сразу после Ubuntu сама должна предложить этот вариант).

В большинстве случаев в Ubuntu все должно работать из коробки, без дополнительной настройки, если не работает, нужно больше информации об вашем железе и проблемах, с которыми вы сталкиваетесь.

Comment: "в Ubuntu все должно работать из коробки", но при этом при каждом обновлении у меня слетает grub, поэтому лучше поставить lts и не трогать его пока петух не клюнет )) либо пока нужного опыта не наберется, т.к. проблема решается за пару минут (если знать как решать)

Comment: @BOPOH, а какая у вас версия? Если *sid*, то ясное дело, он будет нестабилен, учитывая, что он набирается из Debian-овских *testing* и *unstable*.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, подразумевается LTS - версия с расширенной длительностью поддержки, читай выхода обновлений. На сегодняшний день таких две: 14.04.4 и недавно вышедшая 16.04. Добываются вот тут, до Яндекса часто встречается быстрый канал:
http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/14.04.4/
http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/16.04/
Поставится и запустится она и без каких-либо линукс-специфичных знаний.
Документация по конкретным вопросам весьма толковая и её много. В принципе - Ubuntu хороший вариант для начала с низким порогом входа.